# Magento Import "blank" errors even when uploading export file

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am running into issues when uploading inventory files using the Dataflow import. I am only importing about 500 items but at record 42 it seems to find an error and just display a blank red bar, no description of the error. If I run the import with less than 40 lines I don't get an error.

To eliminate my format/coding I exported the product stock file, and then tried importing the same file and get the same "blank" errors. I have tried just about everything I could search for without any luck. seeing if anyone else has an idea or something else I could try.

Magento version - 1.9.2.1

Comment: Most case it may be  memory_limit issue. and max_execution time

Comment: I initially thought it was a memory issue as well, I should have mentioned it but I already changed the .htaccess file to: #php_value memory_limit 2048M & #php_value max_execution_time 88000, with no change in the performance. Is there anywhere else that could be limiting the memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

You should try by getting your server limits increased:

Some thing like this

```
max_execution_time = 36000 ; // Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ;  // Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 1024M ; // Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (32MB)
```

OR,

You try the following code by replace in index.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000);
```

Also Check out  [Customer CSV export fails with blank page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15903/customer-csv-export-fails-with-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but here's what i did to overcome the same issue.

Split your CSV product file into little CSV files, consisting of 40 products each, with the help of a free online CSV splitter - http://splitfile.vavro.me (I had a CSV file of 3000+ products. So it got split into 75 files.)

Then upload all those little CSV files to your server's "var/import/" folder. Now login into your magento's back-end, go to System>Import/Export>Dataflow-Profiles, choose your profile then go to 'Run-Profile'. Here you can see all the uploaded CSV files listed in a drop-down. Now execute the files one by one. Pretty long process, but worth it.

Note that after executing each file, you need to wait for at least 2 minutes to get the indexes refreshed. Or else you might end up getting the same red blank errors again!